# java parse a certain subsection using string split

Tags: java, string

Help would be appreciated, I have a string such as:
APP_RUNTIME_ERB3242322_1_P3A97.tar.gz

and I would like to parse it and get the following:
P3A97

The string will change in time but basically I need the last five alphanumerical letters before the .tar.gz part whenever I get feed this string data.

I can use the java string split method but I do not know what regex I can use to get the last 5 characters.

Comment: Why not split on `_` or `.`. Or you could split twice.

Comment: If it's always the five last characters before `.tar.gz`you could use the substring method with the length of the string -12 (or something, I didn't count) to get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, str.lastIndexOf(".tar.gz"))
```

Comment: Well who knows what dots can appear in the name itself

Comment: Then `str.indexOf(".tar.gz")`? Lol. just nitpicking ;)

Comment: I like this solution a lot more than the one I have.  Nice thinking. :)

Comment: Why would you do this instead of a simple substring from len - 12 through len - 7?

Comment: There is nothing in the requirement to suggest that the solution needs a `split` or `lastIndexOf` and you did not explain why OP should use it. I do think this clearly merits a downvote. Guess you will get to keep your secret.

Answer (score 1):

You can split based on "_" initially and then take the last token that it gives you.  Then you can split on "." and take the first token that it gives you.  This of course depends on whether the format will always have the same number of tokens per split.

Demonstrated:

`APP_RUNTIME_ERB3242322_1_P3A97.tar.gz` into
`APP`

`RUNTIME`

`ERB3242322`

`1`

`P3A97.tar.gz`

And then split `P3A97.tar.gz` into `P3A97` `tar` and `gz`

Answer (score 1):

```
...
String str = "APP_RUNTIME_ERB3242322_1_P3A97.tar.gz";
String lastChars = str.substring(str.length() - 12).replace(".tar.gz", "");

System.out.print(lastChars);

P3A97
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need the last five alphanumerical letters before the .tar.gz part whenever I get feed this string data.
>
> I can use the java string split method but I do not know what regex I can use to get the last 5 characters

You do NOT need regexp here. Besides what you have mentioned, if `.tar.gz` can be assumed to be at the end of the string then you are looking for a `substring`:

```
starting at (length of the string) - length(.tar.gz) - 5
ending at above index + 5
```